# How to custom video player of UIWebView

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview

I want to make a customized video player for UIWebView. 
I have 2 ideas about it:
1. hook the notifications of UIMoviePlayer***, but I can't get any information about the current player from the notification, so I can't replace it with my custom video player
2. replace video.play in js, use my js to tell objective c to launch my video player. But it only works for some website, not for all.

Is there any solution for launch custom video player for UIWebView?

Comment: If native is not an option then why not just make a custom video player with html5?

Comment: We need a common player for all video websites since our app is a web browser.

Comment: Gotcha... This might help: http://maniacdev.com/2013/02/open-source-ios-control-providing-a-full-featured-custom-video-player